# VBA - Close All Workbooks Except Specific Ones

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot find any solution for this anywhere. There are plenty of sources that help you close all the workbooks except the active one, but I need specific workbooks to remain open.

So for example, if there are 10 workbooks open, I need to close 7 of them and keep 3 of them open..

The closest solution I found was here:

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/73743-close-all-open-workbooks-except

```
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Workbooks
    Select Case Ucase(wb.name)
        Case "BOOK1.XLS", "BOOK2.XLS", Ucase(ThisWorkbook.name)
            'Code, if any
        Case Else
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End Select
Next wb
```

But this does not work. It closed Book2 and only Book1 was left open.

As far as I can see, both Book1 and Book2 were supposed to stay open..

When I debug and use Debug.Print in the immediate window I get this:

*Book1.xlsx*

*Book2.xlsx*

*Book3.xlsx*

It basically just prints out the 3 workbooks names that are open.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with *"does not work"*? Have you used the debugger to check what happens?

Comment: @FunThomas Apologies, I updated the question..

Comment: @EitelDagnin Add the line `Debug.Print Ucase(wb.name)` before the `Select Case` for debug, run the code, and post the immediate window output.

Comment: @FunThomas Kindly see updated question.

Comment: So you can see that it is .xlsx extention? Maybe change your code according...

Comment: You told it to look for XLS, while the book names were XLSX so it should have closed them all.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The code I posted is straight from the original source. In my code the book names and extensions are not the same.. But that is all that is different, the name and extension. The rest of the code is exactly the same.

Comment: @JvdV Please see comment above..

Comment: @Eitel Dagnin, i see. The proposed answer is working nicely though. Perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it's working for me.
You can adapt the vars "wbStayOpenx" :

```
Dim wbStayOpen1 As String
Dim wbStayOpen2 As String
Dim currentwb As String

wbStayOpen1 = "BOOK1.XLS"
wbStayOpen2 = "BOOK2.XLS"
currentwb = ThisWorkbook.Name


Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Workbooks

    If wb.Name <> wbStayOpen1 And wb.Name <> wbStayOpen2 And wb.Name <> currentwb Then
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If

Next wb
```

Comment: Cool, happy to help you